# Bokeh resize - plot overshadows widgets

Tags: python, bokeh

In the simple bokeh demo example [`slider.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py)([demo](http://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/sliders)) one can apply the resize tool to expand the plot figure.

If one increases its width, however, the plot first uses up the space taken by the slider widgets, then starts expanding to the right:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

The widgets are in a [`VBoxForm`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/reference/models/widgets.layouts.html#bokeh.models.widgets.layouts.VBoxForm), and I presume the problem lies (t)here:

```
inputs = VBoxForm(children=[text, offset, amplitude, phase, freq])

curdoc().add_root(HBox(children=[inputs, plot], width=800))
```

How can I make bokeh preserve the widget size, or alternatively left-align the plot (so I can increase the size of the container without changing the initial look)?

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh `0.12.9` the `ResizeTool` has been removed (after a previous period of deprecation). So this situation is no longer possible in that sense.